# What's the name of development for vue file + vue cli + npm

Tags: vue.js

If i want to tell other people the project is using npm + vue.cli + .vue file,it's also call `vue.js` ?

[image]

Because i've tried to use `vue.js` name but most people think it's import vue.js and pure js script,like below photo :

[image]

Comment: it is just vue.js

Comment: Perhaps say that you are making SPA's with vue, but all the CLI does is to take care of the webpacky stuff and scaffolding for you. You are mostly doing the same thing anyway so there is not much need for different terminology.

Comment: @ippi  thanks,i got it,i would try to use `nodejs+vue` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, you're using Vue single-file-components (.vue files).

I would refer to it as a Vue Web App